# How can I run separate PHP code on a domain with WordPress installed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I mean to say that I have installed WordPress on a domain. Its root directory now contains files like: `.htaccess`, `wp-signup.php`, `wp-settings.php` etc.

The `wp-content` folder contains other information like the theme, plugins etc.

If I had not installed WordPress, I could upload a file like `random-names.php` inside the root directory and simply access it inside the browser.

Is there a safe way for me to do the same thing with WordPress installed?

The file `random-names.php` has nothing to do with WordPress. It just generates random names in vanilla PHP.

I hope that I made the question clear. Let me know if I need to explain anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you only need to use the exact url to the file
For example: `http://example.com/random-names.php` will call the file even if WordPress is in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Does that mean I am safe as long as I don't use any filenames which conflict with names used by WordPress?

Comment: Yes, you cannot name the file with the same name than other file, you will overwrite it ;)

Comment: I meant to say that let's say I create a file called `get-file-info.php`. Now, if in one of its future updates, WordPress or any of the plugins that I have installed also create a file called `get-file-info.php`.

This will override my original file. The same goes for any tables names etc.

Should I append random characters to my file and table names to avoid the conflict? Is there a specific naming convention that I can follow to avoid future conflicts?

Thanks again Alex. :)

Comment: @VineetSharma you should not have any problem, WordPress files starts with "wp-" or are stored in some of the "wp-*" folders. Also, the files in the website root usually don't change. So, don use "wp-" prefix in your file or store it in a custom folder. Anyway, the best thing to do is create a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can still drop the `random-names.php` file in the root directory of the server, or in your theme directory. It won't harm WordPress in any way since WordPress doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Trevor. :)

I marked the other answer as correct because it was posted before yours. I am giving yours an upvote.